Middle ware Error Handler not getting triggered in Express with TYpeScript
I'm new to express
I am trying to implement exception handling in my Prisma-Express-Typescript project.
I have spent a good amount of time on both Google and YouTube, but could not solve the issue.
ISSUE
The application crashes and the error is not returning to Frontend(i.e postman).But the error is visible at Vscode terminal. The error does goes to postman when I wrap my error statement in try-catch, but even so the the application still crashes.
Implementation
auth.ts
export const signup = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  let { email, password, name } = req.body;
  let user = await prismaClient.user.findFirst({ where: { email } });

  if (user) {
    throw new ConflictException("Email already exists");
  }
  // do other stuff...
}; 

Exception.ts
export class HttpException extends Error {
  status: Exception;
  message: string;

  constructor(message: string, status: Exception) {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

export class ConflictException extends HttpException {
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message, Exception.ConflictException);
  }
}

export enum Exception {
  NotFoundException = 404,
  ConflictException = 409,
}

middleware.ts
import { ErrorRequestHandler, NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { HttpException } from "../exceptions/http-exception";

export const errorMiddleware: ErrorRequestHandler = (
  error: HttpException,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {

  console.log("Error Middleware Triggered");

  res.status(error.status).send({
    message: error.message,
    status: error.status,
  });
};

index.ts
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import { PORT } from "./secrets";
import rootRouter from "./routes/root";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

import "express-async-errors";

import { errorMiddleware } from "./middlewares/api-errors";

const app: Express = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api", rootRouter);

export const prismaClient = new PrismaClient();

app.use(errorMiddleware);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});

I am using express-async-errors as well
I tried this as well Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
export class HttpException extends Error {
  status: number;
  message: string;

  constructor(message: string, status: number) {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
  }
}

The issue is the middleware does not get triggered but when I put this line, in try catch
throw new ConflictException("Email already exists");

The console("Error Middleware Triggered") is printed at Terminal and the exception is shown in Postman but the application crashes as well
